# Logic to generate first- and second-order connections between observation pairs

Tags: r, logic

I have three teams, each with 8 or 9 players (in the real data there are thousands of teams with 8 to 16 players). I would like to identify two types of connections between pairs of teams. For *first order connections* between two teams, the same player plays on both teams. I can correctly generate these connections (see below). For *second order connections* at least one player from each team plays together on a third team. In the example below, player "a" plays for team "a" and player "b" plays for team "b" and players "a" and "b" both play for team "c", so that teams "a" and "b" have a *second order connection*.

The code below properly handles the first order connections. It also correctly handles the second order connections (here between teams "a" and "b" via team "c"), but it also flags bad second order connections by counting connections via the same team. I can't figure out the logic to ignore these cases. In the real data with thousands of teams I won't be able to manually ignore these cases.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
# generic data
dat <- data.frame(team=rep(letters[1:3],
                           length.out=26),
                  man=letters)
# dat$man[2] <- "a" # one first-order connection
dat$man[3] <- "a" # one second-order connection
dat$man[6] <- "b" # one second-order connection

# first order
temp1 <- merge(x=dat, y=dat, by=NULL)
temp2 <- temp1
temp1$sameMan <- 1*with(temp1, man.x == man.y)
order1 <- aggregate(sameMan ~ team.x + team.y, 
                    data=temp1, 
                    FUN=sum)
subset(order1, team.x != team.y)

# second order
temp2$sameTeam <- 1*with(temp2, (team.x == team.y))
temp2 <- aggregate(sameTeam ~ man.x + man.y,
                   data=temp2,
                   FUN=sum)
temp2 <- merge(x=temp1, y=temp2)
order2 <- aggregate(sameTeam ~ team.x + team.y, 
                    data=temp2, 
                    FUN=sum)
subset(order2, team.x != team.y)

# here the correct output is:
order2$sameTeamCorrect <- 0
order2$sameTeamCorrect[c(2, 4)] <- 1
subset(order2, team.x != team.y)
```

This yields:

```
> subset(order2, team.x != team.y)
  team.x team.y sameTeam sameTeamCorrect
2      b      a        1               1
3      c      a       17               0
4      a      b        1               1
6      c      b       17               0
7      a      c       17               0
8      b      c       17               0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a problem from networking theory.

If we have `n` players distributed across `k` teams, we can define a matrix `M` with `n` rows and `k` columns (players in rows, teams in columns). Then `M[i,j] = 1` if player `i` is on team `j`, 0 otherwise. With this definition, the matrix

> A = M<sup>T</sup> × M

is a symmetric `k x k` matrix where the diagonal elements are the number of players on each team, and `A[i,j]` gives the number of players that team `i` and team `j` have in common. So if `A[i,j] > 0`, team `i` and team `j` have a first order connection. In your case you care if they are connected, not the number of players in common, so we normalize A by zeroing out the diagonal and converting any elements > 0 to 1. This is the matrix of first order connections.

> C<sup>(1)</sup> = sign( A - diag(A) )

Second order connections can then be found as

> C<sup>(1)</sup> × C<sup>(1)</sup>

The `[i,j]` element of this matrix will be > 0 if team `i` and team `j` have a second order connection. But there is a problem: teams with second order connections can also have first order connections. I assume you want to discount for that. To do that we normalize as before and subtract `C.1` (which has the first order connections). Any element > 0 in the result represents a second order connection absent a first order connection.

Using a slightly modified version of your example (designating the teams with capital letters),

```
dat <- data.frame(team=rep(LETTERS[1:3],length.out=26),
                  man=letters)
dat$man[3] <- "a" # one second-order connection
dat$man[6] <- "b" # one second-order connection
# team - player matrix
M <- matrix(0,nr=length(unique(dat$man)),nc=length(unique(dat$team)))
rownames(M) <- unique(dat$man)
colnames(M) <- unique(dat$team)
M[as.matrix(dat[,2:1])] <- 1
head(M)
#   A B C
# a 1 0 1
# b 0 1 1
# d 1 0 0
# e 0 1 0
# g 1 0 0
# h 0 1 0
```

Adjacency matrix, first and second order connections.

```
A <- t(M) %*% M
A
#   A B C
# A 9 0 1
# B 0 9 1
# C 1 1 8

C.1 <- sign(A) - diag(nc=ncol(A),nr=nrow(A))
C.1   # A and C connected; B and C connected; A and B not connected
#   A B C
# A 0 0 1
# B 0 0 1
# C 1 1 0

C.2 <- C.1 %*% C.1 - C.1
C.2 <- ifelse(C.2>0,1,0) - diag(nc=ncol(A),nr=nrow(A))
C.2   # A and B have a second order connection, but not first order
#   A B C
# A 0 1 0
# B 1 0 0
# C 0 0 0
```

Finally, you can use the `igraph` package to convert the adjacency matric `A` into an `igraph` object and then identify the first and second order connections directly using the `neighbors(...)` function. If you're going to be doing a lot of this I'd suggest to invest the time to learn that package.

Answer (score 0):

So ... if the concern is the items in the first and third column, then why not:

```
> order2 <- aggregate(sameTeam ~ team.x + team.y, 
+                     data=temp2, subset= team.x != team.y,
+                     FUN=sum)
> subset(order2, team.x != team.y)
  team.x team.y sameTeam
1      b      a        0
2      c      a        0
3      a      b        0
4      c      b        0
5      a      c        0
6      b      c        0
>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that `aggregate` accepts a `subset` argument. But the correct output will show the a-b pair as having one second-order connection. I need to discount the relation when it is in the current team, but I can't figure out how to handle that case. Thanks!